# Program to automatically screenshot or notify if certain numbers, $0.00 is shown on the screen?

Tags: automation, macros

I'm testing a website to see if a price is $0.00 and set up an automatic clicker to click through the different options. It will take hours to go through though. Is there a program that reads the displayed number and tracks if and when the numbers are $0.00 or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

For something this specific my first thought is to write a web scraper yourself. If you have any coding knowledge (and even if you don't), drafting something up in Python would probably be the most time-effective solution compared to searching for an existing tool that could do this.

Basically you'd just need it to make an HTTP request to the site, parse the HTML response for the value in question, and somehow grab a screenshot of the page (or maybe notify you/collect other data, whatever you see fit). [This article is a great resource if you're interested.](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/)